# How to create a radiobutton group using an editor template in Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, mvc-editor-templates

I have the following model

```
 public class FilterSetting
{
    public FilterType Type { get; set; }
    public ShowOption Option { get; set; }
    public bool IsMultiple { get; set; }
    public List<int> SelectedValues { get; set; }
    public List<SelectListItem> Values { get; set; }
    public int RowCount { get; set; }
}
public enum ShowOption
{
    Common,
    Also,
    All
}
```

I want to create a radio button group for the ShowOption enum, but I want to display that group using an editor template because I have another model that creates a list of FilterSetting and it will display about 7 FilterSettings each of one must have a group of 3 radio buttons for the ShowOption property.

The problem is when razor is rendering the radio buttons from the editor template it uses the same name for every radio button (name="filter.Option") and I don't know how to set the value.

This is my editor template

```
@model Models.FilterSetting


@Html.RadioButtonFor(f => f.Option, "Common", new { id = ""+ Model.Type })
@Html.Label(""+Model.Type, "Show only common assets")
<br />
@Html.RadioButtonFor(f => f.Option, "Also", new { id = "" + Model.Type })
@Html.Label(""+Model.Type, "Also show assets matching the values selected below")
<br />
@Html.RadioButtonFor(f => f.Option, "All", new { id = "" + Model.Type })
@Html.Label(""+Model.Type, "Show all assets")
<br />


@if (Model.IsMultiple)
{
    @Html.ListBoxFor(f => f.SelectedValues, Model.Values)
}
else
{ 
    @Html.DropDownListFor(f => f.SelectedValues, Model.Values, new { size = "4" })
}
```

I tried passing the name on the htmlAttributes object but it doesn't work.

**EDIT:**
Apparently the issue is the way I am calling the editor.
I'm calling it in this way

```
@foreach (var filter in Model.FilterSettings)
{
      ....
      @Html.EditorFor(f => filter)
}
```

And when I call it like this

```
@Html.EditorFor(f => f.filterSettings)
```

The radio buttons work properly. What's happening when I do the for each?

Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

When you call the `Editor/EditorFor` for a collection Razor will keep track of the names and ids generated and so you will get the names generated as for ex. `Addresses[0].Line1`, `Addresses[1].Line1`...

But when you iterate the collection yourself and call the editor for the each model razor don't keeps the track for the names and ids (how should it be? is that won't be more complicated?) and it's thinks as a new control going to be rendered in the page.

Answer (score 0):

Usually I use an @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.id) and @Html.HiddenFor(x=>x.name), try this